# Unable to attach a projection before creating a GDAL image

Tags: python, gdal, coordinate-system

I'm unable to add a projection to a newly-created `raster` with `GDAL-python`, using the code below:

```py
arr = np.random.rand(600, 400)
filename = 'path_to_file_'
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
x_size = arr.shape[1]
y_size = arr.shape[0]

dataset = driver.Create(filename, x_size, y_size,
                        eType=gdal.GDT_Float32)
dataset.SetProjection(projection)
dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr)
```

It's expected in the code above that the projection isn't attached to the dataset, because the dataset has already been written when the projection is added to it.
Is there another way to create an image in a way that the `projection` is attached to the saved image?

Note that the `projection` (`WGS84`) that I'm trying to attach to the image to create was extracted from an image used as input to create the newly-created image (i.e. I'm just trying to keep the projection of the source image in the image to save). Here is the `string` returned by `dataset.GetProjection()` (i.e. the content of the variable `projection`):

> 'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",SPHEROID["WGS
>   84",6378137.0,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AXIS["Geodetic
>   longitude",EAST],AXIS["Geodetic
>   latitude",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine. Make sure you flush the writes to disk by dereferencing the `dataset` variable (a well known python GDAL "[gotcha](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#Savingandclosingdatasetsdatasources)").

### Working example:

```python
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(600, 400)
filename = 'path_to_file.tif'
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
x_size = arr.shape[1]
y_size = arr.shape[0]
projection = 'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137.0,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwicbashh",0.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AXIS["Geodetic longitude",EAST],AXIS["Geodetic latitude",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]'

dataset = driver.Create(filename, x_size, y_size,
                        eType=gdal.GDT_Float32)
dataset.SetProjection(projection)
dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr)

del dataset # dereference the variable so writes get flushed to disk
```

### `gdalinfo` output:

```
gdalinfo path_to_file.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: path_to_file.tif
Size is 400, 600
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  600.0)
Upper Right (  400.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  400.0,  600.0)
Center      (  200.0,  300.0)
Band 1 Block=400x5 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: It's probably working but I can't verify it for the time being, because the image I'm generating with [SNAP](http://step.esa.int/main/download/) seems to lack the right ellipsoid (even when I'm terrain-correcting it with `WGS84` as the map projection). I noticed this problem both with `projection.GetProjection` and with `QGIS`. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: @hakim you can [ask another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I've tested your code with and without `del dataset`, and the projection was the same both with `gdalinfo` and with `dataset.GetProjection` (I'm using `gdal 2.1.2`). I think `SNAP` is unable to read the coordinates because of the `Corner Coordinates` parameter, which is expressed in pixels instead of being given as a (lat, lon) angle in degrees. Do you know how to convert this parameter to degrees?

Comment: @hakim Using `del` to dereference the dataset is only required if you need to access the dataset before your script finishes (or you use an IDE that holds the variables open after the script finishes). I don't know why snap doesn't understand the gdal georeferencing.

Comment: Yes I've noticed that without `del`, the image isn't written until a quit the `python prompt`.

Comment: For future visitors, I've managed to make `SNAP` show the geocoordinates by attaching these using `dataset.SetGeoTransform(geocoordinates)`.

Comment: @hakim yes that is correct. If you had asked about attaching georeferencing as well as projection info I would have included that in the example.